# Custom HtmlHelper (image inside an ActionLink)

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc-3

I have seen this done a few different ways, but not specifically what I am looking for.  I currently have a custom HtmlHelper that adds "class='currentPage'" to an ActionLink to highlight the current page in a navigation system.

```
public static MvcHtmlString MenuItem(
            this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
            string text,
            string action,
            string controller
        )
        {
            string value;
            var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;
            var currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
            var currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
            if (string.Equals(currentAction, action, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                string.Equals(currentController, controller, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                value = htmlHelper.ActionLink(text, action, new { controller = controller }, new { @class = "currentPage" }).ToHtmlString();
                return MvcHtmlString.Create(value.ToString());
            }

            value = htmlHelper.ActionLink(text, action, controller).ToHtmlString();
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(value.ToString());
        }
```

This works wonderfully, but I have an admin area where I also have an image associated with each menu item.  The image is located within the link like so:

```
<li><a href="/Admin/Blog"><img src="/Content/images/icons/page_edit.png" alt="" /> Blog</a></li>
```

I want to create an override method for "MenuItem" that adds the image inside the ActionLink, but I am a bit stumped.  Currently I have the following, which puts the img tag on the outside...

```
public static MvcHtmlString MenuItem(
            this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
            bool isAdmin,
            string text,
            string action,
            string controller
        )
        {
            string value;
            var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;
            var currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
            var currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");

            value = "<img src='/Content/images/admin_icons/" + text + ".png' alt='' /> ";

            if (string.Equals(currentAction, action, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                string.Equals(currentController, controller, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                value += htmlHelper.ActionLink(text, action, new { controller = controller }, new { @class = "currentPage" }).ToHtmlString();

            }
            else
            {
                value += htmlHelper.ActionLink(text, action, controller).ToHtmlString();
            }

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(value.ToString());
        }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would generate the URL using UrlHelper, and then format the string. My example does not deal with adding the conditional class, but that should be easy to include.

```
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        var url = urlHelper.Action(action, controller);
        var imgUrl = urlHelper.Content("~/Content/images/icons/page_edit.png");
        var html = string.Format("<li><a href=\"{0}\"><img src=\"{2}\" alt=\"\" />{1}</a></li>", url, text, imgUrl);
        return new MvcHtmlString(html);
```

Comment: var html = string.Format("<li><a href=\"{0}\"><img src=\"{3}\" alt=\"\" />{1}</a></li>", url, text, imgUrl); "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list."  Is this formatted correctly?

Comment: Figured it out... didn't see the numbers were screwed up.  Works great, thank you!